# MySQL/MariaDB: can a SELECT query block an INSERT query?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, locking, insert, blocking

Let's suppose that I have a query in the form:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (...) select ... from tableB;
```

Now, is it possible that this query, while executing, blocks plain `INSERT` statements to `tableB`? Additional information:

- All tables are InnoDB
- There are no explicit transactions (autocommit is on)
- There is NOT a `FOR UPDATE` clause in the `SELECT` statement (I'm not even sure if it would be possible to do it in an `INSERT...SELECT` construct)
- The actual SELECT query is obviously more complicated and involves grouping and unions, but those shouldn't change anything, right?
- Transaction isolation level for all queries is the default `REPEATABLE READ`
- The precise database version is MariaDB 10.0.12

Comment: Perhaps we should work on optimizing the `SELECT`?

Comment: @RickJames - Yeah we did. In fact we realized that we don't need it at all and now the whole query is gone. :) I just wanted to know if it was likely that this was the culprit, because we weren't sure. It _did_ run concurrently with other problems we had, but correlation isn't causation after all. However now it looks like it indeed was the problem and I learned something new today. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `SELECT` is a locking select in this case.

If you use `SELECT` in any query that changes data, it is implicitly a [locking query](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lock-in-share-mode/) as if you had used `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. This puts a shared lock on the rows it reads.

Any other statement that changes data acts the same way. This includes cases like:

- `INSERT ... SELECT ...`
- `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`
- `SELECT ... INTO variable` or `... INTO OUTFILE`
- `SET @variable = (SELECT ...)`
- A trigger on `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` that runs a `SELECT` in its body.
- Subqueries in `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements
- other cases...

A shared lock may be held by multiple concurrent sessions. So you could do this `INSERT ... SELECT` query in multiple transactions. They won't conflict with each other.

But an `INSERT` to tableB must have an exclusive lock. An exclusive lock won't be granted if there are any shared locks present.

Comment: Awesome! I suspected that. It would be even more awesome if there was a link to the documentation that states this. Currently I can't find it (your link doesn't say it).

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/triggers-and-implicit-locks/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html  for example.

Comment: See also this other post from 7 years ago, also by Bill Karwin. My personal preferred solution is the one under the "A Workaround" heading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23816970/1797579

Comment: Great! Thanks! Wish I could upvote twice! :)

Comment: @Vilx- With your reputation greater than 600, you should be able to upvote any detail that helped you.

Comment: @WilsonHauck You mean like comment upvotes? Sure, but that doesn't grant rep. :)

Comment: With your 600+ reputation, you can even Upvote someone's Answer if it helped you and Accept it as the BEST answer.  View your profile, you clearly have Reputation enabling upvotes and ability to Accept an Answer.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, my answer was accepted as best answer. At least I see a green checkmark by my answer, indicating that Vilx marked it as the best answer. Are you suggesting that they could accept my other answer from 7 years ago that another user linked to? That one was already accepted by the person who asked that question.

Comment: @Bill Karwin, You may find that Answers to a 7 year old question can be voted on and accepted by anyone with enough reputation.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, Yes I'm aware that a person with 15 rep can vote up any answer. But as far as I know, no reputation score allows one to accept an answer for another's questions. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges